# Styles from generic.xaml are not applied

Tags: wpf, styles, themes, generic.xaml

I made a class library assembly in which I created custom controls, and I defined the default styles in the generic.xaml file.

It seems this is a quite common problem, as long as many people are posting about it.
However I couldn't find any useful answer for my case.

- the generic.xaml is in the Themes folder.
- the generix.xaml file Build Action is set to Page.
- the ThemeInfo is properly defined in my AssemblyInfo.cs.

In my test application, if I manually merge the generic.xaml file from my custom controls assembly into the application App.xaml file like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyControlsAssembly;component/Themes/generic.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

then the custom controls are properly themed, but if I do not manually merge the generic.xaml, the controls appear with the default Windows theme.

Could you please tell me what am I forgetting and/or doing wrong ?

Additional info:

- My ThemeInfo assembly attribute is defined as follow:

  `[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]`

  (Note: the result is just the same with any combination of parameters for the ThemeInfo attribute)
- There are two others .xaml files beside the generic.xaml file in the Themes folder.
- There is a subfolder in the Themes folder that itself contains another .xaml file.

Comment: Do you still have the DefaultStyleKeyProperty set in a static constructor on your custom controls?

Comment: Any luck figuring this one out?  I have almost the same exact thing going on with my custom controls assembly. If I add a reference in App.config to the generic.xaml file then the controls are themed.  If I leave this out I get nothing.

Comment: Does this link apply? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e1fb162-e828-4fd9-832f-d2791c1980b4/isnt-genericxaml-supposed-to-loaded-automatically
I took am facing the same problem, and I think this is the root cause

Comment: Any solution to this issue? I'm experiencing the exact same thing, and following the steps suggested here or in http://blogs.magnatis.com/tim/dude-wheres-my-default-style does not help. I need to include the merge in App.xaml as in this post.

Comment: Adding ThemeInfo in AssemblyInfo.cs of the control library did the trick for me. I used (None, SourceAssembly).

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but **are you sure your theme is located at [PROJECT]\Themes\Generic.xaml?** I had the same problem, my themes  did not load and it turned out because I had an extra folder in the path ([PROJECT]\MySubProject\Themes\Generic.xaml).

Answer (score 18):

To apply default styles in Themes\Generic.xaml in my custom controls library I decided to seek inspiration from a well established open source controls library ([MahApps](http://mahapps.com/)). This project gives you a really good example of how to structure and layout a custom controls library.

Cut a long story short, to get your default styles in Themes\Generic.xaml you need to include the following in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in your custom controls library:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

In my case, my custom controls AssemblyInfo.cs looked something like:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("...")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitleAttribute("...")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProductAttribute("...")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("...")]
```

Answer (score 14):

You need the following line in your custom control constructor:

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    static MyCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
    }
}
```

Then if you have a generic.xaml file inside themes folder, with the following sample style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                <Border>
                    <Label>Testing...</Label>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now the style will get automatically applied without any extra merging.

Comment: This does not work for me. Look at my comment on the initial question

Comment: Start with a blank solution and see if you can get it to work from there?

Comment: That is what I am doing. I am deriving from Xceed Data Grid. If I create a new MyControl : Control or MyButton : Button, it works. Perhaps it is Xceed theme support that comes into play here, and I need to look into their tutorials on themes, or simply accept the merge dictionary in my application. Unless other ideas surface.

Answer (score 1):

In My case I forget to remove the `x:Key` from `<Style>` tag.

**Wrong:**

```
<Style TargetType="controls:IpTextBox" x:Key="MyControlStyle">
```

**Correct:**

```
<Style TargetType="controls:IpTextBox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in WPF, but it works for me in Silverlight:

Constructor:

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    static MyCustomControl()
    {
        this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyCustomControlStyle"];
    }
}
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomControlStyle" TargetType="{local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{local:MyCustomControl}">
                <Border>
                    <Label>Testing...</Label>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem due to the following attribute in the custom control assembly:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

Changing `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite` to `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly` or removing the second parameter completely fixed the problem for me (you can also remove the attribute if you do not need to define the neutral language of your assembly).