# Custom control styles not working (via Generic.xaml)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, themes

I have several several styles and templates for both standard WPF controls and custom controls in an external custom control libary project. For each control, there's a `ResourceDictionary` in my `\Themes` folder, along with a `Generic.xaml` which contains a merged dictionary of all the other XAML files.

I made sure that:

- The `Generic.xaml` is in the `Themes\` folder within the root of my project
- The `Generic.xaml` has a *Build Action* of `Page`.
- The `Generic.xaml` uses the custom tool flag `MSBuild:Compile`.
- The external library has the following line declared: `[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]`

What I tried:

#### Sources

- `Source="MyControl.xaml"`
- `Source="/MyLibrary;component/Themes/MyControl.xaml"`
- `Source="/MyLibrary;component/Themes/MyControl.xaml"`
- `Source="/pack://application:,,,/Themes/MyControl.xaml"`
- `Source="/pack://application:,,,/MyLibrary;component/Themes/MyControl.xaml"`

#### Application

- Manually referencing the `Generic.xaml` in my application with all possible source declarations

However, nothing works. The application stays completely unthemed, even though I can see that all dictionaries have been loaded when accessing `Application.Current.Resources`.

It's also worth noting that most of my control themes contain additional dynamic resources (for colors etc.), which are loaded manually when the application starts.

It seems that I'm facing the exact same unanswered problem as the OP [in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149167/styles-from-generic-xaml-are-not-applied), however they state that manually referencing the `Generic.xaml` works for them.

Comment: It might help if you post a simplified consumer xaml where you are trying to apply the style and your generic.xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Do you defined following code in static constructor?

DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata (typeof (YourCustomClass),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (typeof (YourCustomClass)));

don't use x:key ="style_name" in resource dictionary

Answer (score 0):

But the question is old, i had same problem and i found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562565/16722051

Only you need to do, add the magic method call named SetResourceReference in your constructor of your custom control.

**UPDATE:**

SetResourceReference will do looking for a style based on type in the resources tree. So if you set manualy the Style of your custom control this will override it.

The correct usage, subscribe the Loaded event, and call the SetResourceReference method when the custom control Style is still null.

This solution make your custom control to work if you manualy set the Style throught the parent control ItemContainerStlye dp and if you not setted, call the SetResourceReference and will find the Style in the Resource tree.

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (Style == null)
            SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, typeof(MyCustomControl));
    };
}
```